# Extend CDS view with group by and/or aggregated fields

Tags: abap, cds

I have the requirement to extend a sap cds view to add one field.
The cds view have a group by clause, therefore I'm getting the following error:

> Parent I_SRVCENTRSHTPURORDITMVH has aggregate function or group by;
> extension not possible

I found a possible solution in the [ABAP Keyword Documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/de-de/abencds_f1_extend_view.htm) by adding the annotation

> @AbapCatalog.viewEnhancementCategory: [#PROJECTION_LIST,#GROUP_BY]

but I don't want to change sap default cds views.

Is there another way to extend this cds?

Comment: 1)"I have the requirement to extend a sap cds view to add one field." and 2)"but I don't want to change sap default cds views." seem contradictory.

Comment: @Ela with [Z CDS Extensions](https://help.sap.com/docs/BTP/f859579898c7494dbe2449bb7f278dcc/cb7a12b0faf44b41b9fc62e57fec55c5.html) it's possible to extend the default view without changing it

Comment: `to add one field` do you wanna add that field into GROUP BY key or as a regular field?

Comment: @Suncatcher - a regular field would be enough